# Positioning buttons beside the input field using CSS

Tags: css, button, position

I want to set the position of buttons next to the input field, but the PLUS button needs to be above the MINUS button. So the height of class button will be same as input field. Could you help me with that? Thank you!

[Current result of code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/n3Ezy.png)

```
    <body>
    <div class="input">
        <input name="number" type="text" readonly value="0" class="arrowsChange">
      </div>


      <script>
        var inputNumber = document.querySelector('.arrowsChange');
        inputNumber.insertAdjacentHTML('afterend', '<div class="buttons"><button onclick="inc()">+</button><button onclick="dec()">-</button></div>');

          function inc() {
            let number = document.querySelector('.arrowsChange');
            number.value = parseInt(number.value) + 1;
            }

            function dec() {
            let number = document.querySelector('.arrowsChange');
                if (parseInt(number.value) > 0) {
                number.value = parseInt(number.value) - 1;
            }
            }
      </script>
</body>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `display: flex;` rule on your input wrapper. Then `display: grid;` on your buttons wrapper.  However, your input will be taller in `height`. I let you figure out how to solve the rest of your expecting.

### See my implementation

```css
.input{
  display: flex;
}
.buttons{
  display: grid;
}
.buttons button {
    height: 15px;
    line-height: 9px;
}
```

```html
<body>
    <div class="input">
        <input name="number" type="text" readonly value="0" class="arrowsChange">
      </div> 
      <script>
        var inputNumber = document.querySelector('.arrowsChange');
        inputNumber.insertAdjacentHTML('afterend', '<div class="buttons"><button onclick="inc()">+</button><button onclick="dec()">-</button></div>');

          function inc() {
            let number = document.querySelector('.arrowsChange');
            number.value = parseInt(number.value) + 1;
            }

            function dec() {
            let number = document.querySelector('.arrowsChange');
                if (parseInt(number.value) > 0) {
                number.value = parseInt(number.value) - 1;
            }
            }
      </script>
</body>
```

You also can try to learn [Bootstrap](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/getting-started/introduction/), which is a frontend framework to help you build responsive and mobile-first websites.

Comment: Thanks, I know to do this. I need to make buttons smaller and the "+" button to be above the "-" button. To have something like arrows when you have input type number. This is just example from big project where I have to apply this :).

Comment: Well here is an example so : `.buttons button {
    height: 15px;
    line-height: 9px;
}`  Otherelse, you have the `input type='number'` which add arrows to get your number higher or lower. [See this link](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_input_type_number.asp)

Comment: I just can't change type because its a part of symfony project, it's generate the form fields. I just have to style input fields which has integer as input value and I have to put this buttons beside the input filed.

Comment: Ok so as I said, try to modify your buttons `height`, then adjust the `line-height` to positions your plus and minus fonts into your buttons. Is it working ? (I modify the SO fiddle to have a full code)